# Is the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional really necessary in Exercise 5.A.28? (Sheldon Axler "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition")

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-subspace

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.
The author assumed that $V$ is finite-dimensional in Exercise 5.A.28.
But I don't think that this assumption is necessary for this exercise.
The author is very careful and the author doesn't usually assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional if not necessary.
Is the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional really necessary for Exercise 5.A.28?

> Exercise 5.A.26:
> Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ is such that every nonzero vector in $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$. Prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.
> Proof:
> Let $v,w$ be arbitrary nonzero elements of $V$.
> Since $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $T$ by assumption, there exist $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $T(v)=\lambda_1 v$ and $T(w)=\lambda_2 w$.
> If $v+w\neq 0$, then there exists $\lambda_3\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $T(v+w)=\lambda_3(v+w)$.
> If $v+w=0$, then $T(v+w)=T(0)=0=0(v+w)$.
> So, there exists $\lambda_3\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $T(v+w)=\lambda_3(v+w)$.
> Since $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$, the following equality holds:
> $\lambda_3(v+w)=\lambda_1 v + \lambda_2 w$.
> So, $(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)v + (\lambda_3-\lambda_2)w=0$.
> If $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, then $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3$.
> If $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent, then $\lambda_3-\lambda_1\neq 0$ and $\lambda_3-\lambda_2\neq 0$, so we can write $w=av$ for some $a\in\mathbb{F}$.
> $T(w)=T(av)=aT(v)=a\lambda_1 v=\lambda_1(av)=\lambda_1 w$ and $T(w)=\lambda_2 w$.
> Since $w\neq 0$, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$.
> So, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$ for any $v\neq 0$.
> Of course, $T(0)=0=\lambda 0$.
> So, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$ for any $v$.
> Since $\lambda v=\lambda I(v)$, $T=\lambda I$.

> Exercise 5.A.28:
> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with $\dim V\geq 3$ and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ is such that every $2$-dimensional subspace of $V$ is invariant under $T$. Prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.
> Proof:
> Let $v$ be an arbitrary nonzero element of $V$.
> Since $\dim V\geq 3$, there exist $v_1,v_2\in V$ such that $v,v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent.
> By assumption $\operatorname{span}(v,v_1)$ and $\operatorname{span} (v,v_2)$ are invariant subspaces of $T$.
> So, $\operatorname{span}(v,v_1)\cap\operatorname{span} (v,v_2)=\operatorname{span} (v)$ is also an invariant subspace of $T$.
> So, $T(v)=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$.
> So, $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$.
> So, by Exercise 5.A.26, $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.

We don't use the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: You're right and you might want to let the author know ([he keeps a list of errata](https://linear.axler.net/LADRErrataThird.html)).

Comment: You are correct that Exercise 28 in Section 5.A of Linear Algebra Done Right (third edition) does not require the hypothesis that V is finite-dimensional. I will drop this hypothesis in the fourth edition of the book. Thank you.

Comment: @SheldonAxler Thank you very much for your comment. And thank you very very much for "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis".